# DocumentDB: Unable to update ALL records - Only 100 records are updated at a time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In my document, when few fields(post,price,desc) i want to turn off the approval flag.

For this problem, I am first turning off the flag for all the records in the document and then turning on the flag for only unique records.

```
function SProc() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var counter = 0;
    var responseBody = {
        updated: 0,
        continuation: true,
        error: "",
        log: ""
    };

    // Validate input.
    getFullListOfPosts();

    // Recursively queries for a document by id w/ support for continuation tokens.
    // Calls findDuplicates(document) as soon as the query returns a document.
    function getFullListOfPosts(continuation) {
        var query = {
            query: "select * from root r ORDER BY r.created.epoch DESC"
        };

        var requestOptions = {
            continuation: continuation
        };

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, proccessFullListOfPosts);

        // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            responseBody.log += "Query not accepted";
            response.setBody(responseBody);
            throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
        }
    }

    function proccessFullListOfPosts(err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            responseBody.error = err;
            throw err;
        }
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            responseBody.log += "Total records: " + documents.length;
            var filtered = documents.filter(function(a) {
                var key = a.posted_by + '|' + a.price + '|' + a.description + '|' + a.compare_price;
                if (!this[key]) {
                    this[key] = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }, Object.create(null))
            for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
                var allRec = documents[i]
                disableAllrecords(allRec);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                var uniqRec = filtered[i]
                enableUniqueRecords(uniqRec);
            }
        }
        if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token;
            // repeat the query w/ the token.
            getFullListOfPosts(responseOptions.continuation);
        }
    }

    function disableAllrecords(element) {
        element.is_approved = false;
        element.likes = 56;
        responseBody.log += " Will disable " + element.id + element.is_approved + element.likes;
        var requestOptions = {
            etag: element._etag
        };
        var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(element._self, element, requestOptions, function(err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err; 
            counter++;
            responseBody.log += " Disabled: " + element.id + " with approval:" + element.is_approved + " Likes:" + element.likes; 
        });
        if (!isAccepted) {
            throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out while disabling");
        }
    }

    function enableUniqueRecords(x) {
        x.is_approved = true;
        x.likes = 65;
        responseBody.log += " Will enable " + x.id + x.is_approved + x.likes;
        var requestOptions = {
            etag: x._etag
        };
        var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(x._self, x, requestOptions, function(err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err; 
            counter++;
            responseBody.log += " Enabled: " + x.id + " with approval:" + x.is_approved + " Likes:" + x.likes; 
        });
        if (!isAccepted) {
            throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out while enabling");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in enableUniqueRecords(). I am not able to understand what and why I am getting an error.

It says:

> Error: {"Errors":["One of the specified pre-condition is not met"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azhar, I guess what fails here is the replaceDocument call. It must be failing because the _etag precondition is not met, which should be because the document was modified by somebody else after this script (transaction) has started. Is this possible case?

To take care of modified documents inside scripts, a retry needs to be done from the client. What you can do is (1) throw an exception (if you want script transaction to be aborted) with custom message or (2) set some custom flag in request body (if you want script actions done so far to commit), recognize this on the client and retry ExecuteStoredProcedure call.

BTW, for stored procedures the _etag pre-condition is not needed, as updating document would fail due to snapshot isolation, if the document was modified after script has started.